# Passing a variable through parameters and modifying it later in the class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

How can I store a variable in a class, and modify it later in program flow?

For example:

```
bool bGlobalStatus = false;

class foo
{
public:

    foo(){}
    ~foo(){}

    void InitGlobalBool(bool &var)
    {

        // I can change the value here, but I want to store the variable and modify it later.
        // var = !var;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // this will be called in program flow ...
        var = !var; // this variable should be in my case bGlobalStatus, depends which variable I put inside the InitGlobalBool function 
    }
};

int main()
{
   foo Foo;
   Foo.InitGlobalBool(bGlobalStatus); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not use a member variable?

Comment: You would store a reference to that member, or create a `std::function` and store that

Comment: because it should not, need to be seperate.

Comment: @Steven.Hawks Then add a pointer to your `foo` class and store a pointer to the variable (you cannot store a reference unless you are prepared to move the code to foos constructor).

Comment: create a pointer `bool *mVar{};`, then inside `InitGlobalBool` type `mVar = &var;`, and finally inside `Update` you do something like `*mVar = !(*mVar);`.

Comment: @Ric You should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
bool bGlobalStatus = false;

class foo
{
public:
    bool *mVar{};
    foo(){}
    ~foo(){}

    void InitGlobalBool(bool &var)
    {

        mVar = &var;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        *mVar = !(*mVar);
    }
};

int main()
{
   foo Foo;
   Foo.InitGlobalBool(bGlobalStatus); 
   return 0;
}
```